# MySQL - Split SELECT query (WHERE IN) into two rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So, I am using MySQL to do a query and have a database like this:

[image: Tables]

I wanted to do a `select` query to show every transaction of Bank A and C based on their prefix. This is the expected result:

[image: Expected Result]

I have done the query as followed:

```
SELECT
    M.merk AS 'Merk',
    COUNT( T.amount ) AS 'Jumlah Transaksi',
    SUM( T.amount ) AS 'Total Amount'
FROM
    tb_transaksiatm T
INNER JOIN tb_issuer I ON
    T.nomor_kartu LIKE CONCAT(I.prefix, '%')
INNER JOIN tb_terminalatm M ON
    T.terminal = M.nomor_terminal
WHERE
    I.bank IN ('A', 'C') # Declare the Bank;
```

But my result is not the same as expected. It combined and summed both rows from Bank A and Bank C. This is my result:

[image: Result]

The question is, how do I split the `WHERE IN` condition into two rows? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. 
*Note: The language is Indonesian.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    M.merk AS 'Merk',
    COUNT( T.amount ) AS 'Jumlah Transaksi',
    SUM( T.amount ) AS 'Total Amount'
FROM
    tb_transaksiatm T
INNER JOIN tb_issuer I ON
    T.nomor_kartu LIKE CONCAT(I.prefix, '%')
INNER JOIN tb_terminalatm M ON
    T.terminal = M.nomor_terminal
WHERE
    I.bank IN ('A', 'C') # Declare the Bank
group by M.merk;
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for a fast answer. I didn't know it was this simple. I will accept your answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an aggregation function such as SUM or COUNT and you do not specify a GROUP BY, it will aggregate all rows together.  Fields such as M.Merk that could vary between the rows being aggregated will have a value taken from an arbitrary one of the rows being aggregated, though modern versions of mysql default to an ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode where selecting such a field will result in an error instead of an arbitrary value.

It sounds like you intend to have a `GROUP BY I.Bank, M.Merk`, though it is confusing that you don't include the bank in your selected fields.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean, but the case was to select only the `M.Merk`, `COUNT`, and `SUM`. The answer by @Alessandro will do the case. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: so if you have the two banks with the same Merk, you want just one row or two?  your question makes it sound like two.

Comment: I have tried this also, and the result is only one row.